# finding parent of nested resource that has multiple types of parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a model like:

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :personal_phone_numbers
  has_many :household_phone_numbers
  has_many :organization_phones

  has_many :people, :through => :personal_phone_numbers
  has_many :households, :through => :household_phone_numbers
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organization_phones
end
```

When viewing a phone number, I'm probably going to be viewing it as a nested resource, so the controller is going to have a params item of one of `person_id`, `household_id`, or `organization_id`

I need the view to have a `link_to "Return", ...` that returns to the correct resource that we came to the phone number from.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using nested resources, you'll need a before filter on your PhoneNumberController that sets the parent object, so you can do `@parent.phone_numbers.build(...)` right? At the same time (before_filter), set the `@parent_path` (`organization_path`, `household_path`...) and you'll have that available in your view to link to.

If you were adding the phone number to each of these things (organization, household...) using `:polymorphic => true` instead of `has_many :through`, you could simply take the @parent that you'll be setting in the PhoneNumbersController `before_filter` and do `polymorphic_path(@parent)` instead.

Comment: If @parent is set in the controller and you have restful routes, you can just do `link_to "Return", @parent`

Comment: Actually, I didn't realize what magic polymorphic_url did.  In my view, all I have to do is `link_to "Return", @parent` and it magically knows what resource to go back to.